# How would you improve the hand?

Tags: creature-design

I'm talking about a saurian-like carapaced creature. No changing parts (retractable, etc), and no bendy parts (because carapace). It needs to do almost anything well (but not great).

Comment: A what kind of hand?

Comment: Are you asking for an alternative design for a hand capable of doing advanced manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

Add another opposing thumb on the other side of the palm.

Allow the tips of each finger to secrete a variable strength adhesive which evaporates a short time after it loses contact with the reptile's body.

Add a sharp ridge along the back of the hand since that flat space doesn't do anything useful now.  The ridge can act as sharpened brass knuckles in a fight, but would also save them the need to carry a pocket knife.

Bio-luminescence from either the palm or finger tips.  From the palm its a flash light and from the fingertips, a work lamp or pen-light.

Comment: Actually, another opposable thiumb doesn't buy you much, and costs a good deal. You lose the anchoring effect of the little finger, which is critical for using tools with any strength. Swing a hammer or sword without curling the little finger over the handle/hilt and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, why can't you have both the little finger and another thumb?  When gripping something or in a fist, it could fold up over the last joints of the four curled fingers, adding more strength to your hold.  And with the adhesive added in, even more.  Try swinging that hammer or sword with a band of duct tape coming up from the back of your hand, over the hilt and glueing the last segment of your four curled fingers in place.

Comment: The overlords from Childhood's End by Arthur C. Clarke had a thumb on each side of their hands.  And if you are still in melee and cant swing a sword, use a katar.

Answer (score 0):

Have microscopic Hairs grow on your fingers and palms. Like some kind of insect, you could use these to walk up walls.